# How to use multiple versions of Wix in same machine?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, wix3.8

I'm having a project with Wix 3.0 and another project with Wix 3.8 versions.
I can't use both versions same time for these projects. Each time i've to unintall/install wix build based on projects.

How to use without uninstall old wix build for the projects.

Anyone please suggest me what has to do to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The technique described here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html can be used on development systems to allow building projects with different versions of the WiX Toolset ...

The problem is in maintaining projects which require different versions, especially if you have multiple developers working on these projects.

Hope this helps!